# Problem installing and removing CiviCRM on a Joomla 3.6.3 site

Tags: joomla, installation

I'm trying to install CiviCRM 4.7.10 on a newly installed Joomla 3.6.2-site. I uploaded the code to a folder on the server, and did an "install from folder". However, this one failed (maybe faulty network connection). However, something was installed, and upon trying to reinstall, I get the following error message:

> Warning: require_once(/home/agslo/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/agslo/public_html/tmp/com_civicrm/admin/configure.php on line 115
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/agslo/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/agslo/public_html/tmp/com_civicrm/admin/configure.php on line 115

According to the Module manager in Joomla, there is a CiviCRM component installed. However when I try to uninstall it, I get an error msg too, saying it cannot find Joomla XML setup file, and I am asked to manually remove it.

Anyone that can assist me in solving this so I can have CiviCRM installed? Either by first removing the component, or by doing a new install.....

Magnus

Answer (score 1):

If the CiviCRM component does not install correctly

(for example you get a blank screen instead of the confirmation page),

delete the ~/components/com_civicrm and

~/administrator/components/com_civicrm and

~/media/civicrm directories manually

and then try each of the following before attempting to reinstall:

Please refer to the below link : this is for 4.5 but still this should work for 4.7 too

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Joomla+Installation+Guide+for+CiviCRM+4.5

I guess this helps !!!

Comment: Hi! Thanks. However, it doesnt help so far. That is the instruction I used in the first place. I do not get a blank screen, I get the errors pasted above - instead of being returned to the Module manager in joomla. Looking at line 115 in the configure.php, this seems to me to be something related to the variable $civicrmUpgrade - my hunch would be that there is something telling the installer that this is an upgrade, not a clean installation. Could that be right? Could there be something in the database doing this (as I did delete all the files you mentioned)?

Comment: And I canno delete the tables with prefix civicrm in the mysql database, I get the error " #1217 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails!

Comment: If you are using PHPMyAdmin to delete the database tables you need untick 'Foreign key check'.  This will allow you delete all of the tables regardless of the foreign key constraints.

Comment: In that case try to create a new Database for Civicrm and try to install Civicrm - that should work

Comment: Hi! Yes I use PHPmyadmin. Where do I untick Foreign key check? Magnus

Comment: In the SQL tab enter:
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
Then when you are done go back to SQL tab and enter:
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

Comment: Additionally, in later versions of PHPMyAdmin there is a tick box to do this.